# Issue while Sending JSON Request

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am facing an issue when i am sending a REST request in JSON format.Some of the parameters are getting missed when it invokes the service.However it works fine when i send the request in xml format.The issue which i am geting throws below error:

```
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "create_session_param"
```

The object mapper class looks as below:

```
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,true);

        JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        // maintain JAXB annotation support
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give the class you're trying to serialize (the relevant parts, anyway) and an example of the JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: @AlexTaylor i have updated the Q.Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` which is for serialization. Remember *serialization* is POJO to JSON. The `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` is the one that actually *adds* the `"create_session_param"` when creating the JSON.

We need JSON to POJO, which is *deserialization*, which has its own feature set. In this case, we need a feature to **un**wrap the root value in the JSON. For that there is

> [`DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE)

So do

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```